# OR operator in switch-case?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Let's take a simple switch-case that looks like:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.someValue :
        case R.id.someOtherValue:
            // do stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

I wonder why it is not allowed to use the `||` operator? Like

```
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.someValue || R.id.someOtherValue:
        // do stuff
        break;
}
```

The `switch-case` construct is pretty similar to an `if-else` statement, you can use the OR operator in an `if` however. What are the backgrounds for a `switch-case` to not accept this operator?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yep. Check my comment for arshajii's answer

Comment: arshajii doesn't seem to have an answer...

Comment: `||` is essentially the default operation of a case statement in the absence of `break`.

Comment: Think about it this way - If switch had the same capability as if-else then why do we need both? It'll be redundant!! The idea of switch is to improve readability as opposed to writing spaghetti code with multiple if else blocks. Arguably switch also gives slightly a better performance due to its simplicity.

Comment: The Ada language does the exact sort of thing you're asking about--you'd say `when Some_Value | Some_Other_Value =>` in a `case` statement.  But the language doesn't use | as an operator, so there's no way this syntax could be ambiguous.  Using || for this purpose in C (Java, etc.) would make the syntax ambiguous, and it's not a good idea to have funky rules with exceptions (like || means one thing in an expression except that it means something different in a different context...).

Comment: Because it's redundant?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> What are the backgrounds for a switch-case to not accept this operator?

Because `case` requires constant expression as its value. And since an `||` expression is not a compile time constant, it is not allowed.

From [JLS Section 14.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

Switch label should have following syntax:

> SwitchLabel:
>       case ConstantExpression :
>        case EnumConstantName :
>        default :

---

### Under the hood:

The reason behind allowing just constant expression with cases can be understood from the [JVM Spec Section 3.10 - Compiling Switches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.10):

> Compilation of switch statements uses the **tableswitch** and **lookupswitch** instructions. The tableswitch instruction is used when the cases of the switch can be efficiently represented as indices into a table of target offsets. The default target of the switch is used if the value of the expression of the switch falls outside the range of valid indices.

So, for the cases label to be used by `tableswitch` as a index into the table of target offsets, the value of the case should be known at compile time. That is only possible if the case value is a constant expression. And `||` expression will be evaluated at runtime, and the value will only be available at that time.

From the same JVM section, the following `switch-case`:

```
switch (i) {
    case 0:  return  0;
    case 1:  return  1;
    case 2:  return  2;
    default: return -1;
}
```

is compiled to:

```
0   iload_1             // Push local variable 1 (argument i)
1   tableswitch 0 to 2: // Valid indices are 0 through 2  (NOTICE This instruction?)
      0: 28             // If i is 0, continue at 28
      1: 30             // If i is 1, continue at 30
      2: 32             // If i is 2, continue at 32
      default:34        // Otherwise, continue at 34
28  iconst_0            // i was 0; push int constant 0...
29  ireturn             // ...and return it
30  iconst_1            // i was 1; push int constant 1...
31  ireturn             // ...and return it
32  iconst_2            // i was 2; push int constant 2...
33  ireturn             // ...and return it
34  iconst_m1           // otherwise push int constant -1...
35  ireturn             // ...and return it
```

So, if the `case` value is not a constant expressions, compiler won't be able to index it into the table of instruction pointers, using `tableswitch` instruction.

Comment: I get the feeling the asker knows this, but is wondering why this restriction is in place to begin with.

Comment: @Maver1ck Probably because there's no need for it, since you can just use the fall-through. Although, this is allowed (and taken to an absurd extreme) in Scala.

Comment: @Maver1ck It might be helpful then to modify the question to state that you know how you're supposed to do it within the given syntax, but you're just wondering why this isn't an acceptable alternative

Comment: @Maver1ck "since an expression is not a compile time constant, it is not allowed." because of this it can execute faster through easier compiler optimization in many cases. It's faster than if statements because of low level tricks and magic.

Comment: @Maver1ck: It's also worth pointing out that `R.id.foo || R.id.bar` doesn't mean anything, in any context (assuming `foo` and `bar` aren't `boolean`).

Comment: A compiler could easily interpret `case 0 || 1` (or some variation of that) as two constants in a lookup table. For example, Java 14 now has the syntax `case 0, 1 -> ...` followed by an expression, a code block, or a throw.

Answer (score 124):

dude do like this

```
    case R.id.someValue :
    case R.id.someOtherValue :
       //do stuff
```

This is same as using OR operator between two values 
Because of this case operator isn't there in switch case

Comment: hey @BalusC this answer actually helped me with my application so I suggest to keep this "answer"

Answer (score 49):

You cannot use || operators in between 2 case. But you can use multiple case values without using a break between them. The program will then jump to the respective case and then it will look for code to execute until it finds a "break". As a result these cases will share the same code.

```
switch(value) 
{ 
    case 0: 
    case 1: 
        // do stuff for if case 0 || case 1 
        break; 
    // other cases 
    default: 
        break; 
}
```

Comment: Never thought of it quite like this, interesting way to do it.

Comment: Or you can use like this also, case 0, 1: //if the case 0 || 1

Comment: This should be the correct answer. even android studio  will show  a suggestion to a merge with duplicate branch

Comment: Java 14 has a new switch statement with syntax like `case 0, 1 -> ...` which can evaluate to an expression, execute a code block, or throw.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know a best approach but I do it as

```
case 'E':
case 'e':
   System.exit(0);
   break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch is not same as if-else-if.

Switch is used when there is one expression that gets evaluated to a value and that value can be one of predefined set of values. If you need to perform multiple boolean / comparions operations run-time then if-else-if needs to be used.

Answer (score 1):

[Since Java 12](https://openjdk.org/jeps/325) and on it is possible to have multiple values in cases:

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.someValue, R.id.someOtherValue:
            // do stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

OR

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.someValue, R.id.someOtherValue -> {/* do stuff */}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still do it like this.

```
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.someValue: case R.id.someOtherValue:
        // do stuff
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using enhanced `switch`

```
switch (value)
{
    case R.id.someValue, R.id.someOtherValue -> // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (array('one', 'two', 'three') as $v) {
    switch ($v) {
        case (function ($v) {
            if ($v == 'two') return $v;
            return 'one';
        })($v):
            echo "$v min \n";
            break;


    }
}
```

this works fine for languages supporting enclosures

Answer (score -1):

helps in some cases.

```
switch(true){
 case a == b: break;
 case a == 2 || a == 3: break;
 default: break;
}
```

Comment: Please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.